# Comment form doesn't submit

Tags: comments

I have inserted comment form to my custom `node.tpl` via `print drupal_render(drupal_get_form("comment_node_{$node->type}_form", (object) array('nid' => $node->nid)));`. It works fine, but form isn't submitted when I click on `Save` button. It submits the data correctly to `comment/reply/<nid>`, but data aren't saved correctly and I'm only redirected back to node page.

I'm using current D7.

Comment: so - you're using a custom form for that ? can you submit this form elsewhere ? why don't you use the standard comment form and alter it according the nodetype ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. I forgot, that I need to enable commenting on individual nodes. Sorry for this stupid mistake. Thanks @rémy